# How to select two geo-points on one page by clicking the Google map?

Tags: google-maps

I have 4 fields and one map on my form. I have to choose Start Location and End location. The start latitude, start longitude, end latitude and end longitude are the four fields. What I have to do is, to choose the start and end locations by clicking on the map. Can anybody suggest me how I should go about doing this?

Thanks,
Saurabh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code to get lat long .

```
function onload()
{
 var map= new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
zoom: 14,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
disableDefaultUI: true
});
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event){
          map.setCenter(event.latLng,14);
           var marker=new GMarker(event.latLng);
           mapadd.push(marker);
           map.addOverlay(marker);
           map.setCenter(event.latLng,12);

var lat =event.latLng.lat();
var lng= event.latLng.lng();

}
```

then u can use these lat and lng varible to get ur locationa and can get directions

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener to the map that listens for a click. When the map is clicked it passes the lat/lng via `event.latLng.lat()` and `event.latLng.lng()`

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', setLatLngs);

```
function setLatLngs( e ) {
    document.getElementById('start_lat').value = e.latLng.lat();
    document.getElementById('start_lng').value = e.latLng.lng();
}
```